# Is DistributionFitTest broken for some cases of TransformedDistribution targets?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Observe:

```
(* create a simple sum of DUs distribution *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
    b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}];

(* get the CDF of that, make my own PD for kicks *)
cdf = CDF[dist, x];
myPD = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", cdf}, {x, 2, 12, 1}];

(* verify - mine and intrinsic are equivalent *)
PDF[myPD, Range[2, 12]] == PDF[dist, Range[2, 12]]
CDF[myPD][Range[2, 12]] == CDF[dist][Range[2, 12]]

(* poop out some RV based on intrinsic *)
rv = RandomVariate[dist, 360];

(* do a fit test on intrinsic, then mine *)
DistributionFitTest[rv, dist, "PearsonChiSquare"]
DistributionFitTest[rv, myPD, "PearsonChiSquare"]

(*

True

True

Indeterminate

0.476108

*)
```

Any ideas why `Indeterminate` results? I do note that doing

```
PDF[dist, {6, 7}]
PDF[myPD, {6, 7}]
```

gives correct results, but doing

```
CDF[dist, {6, 7}]
CDF[myPD, {6, 7}]
```

gives proper results for `myPD`, but a steaming mess for `dist`...

On MMA 9.01/Windows, btw.

Comment: The CDF is required for the chi square test in order to build bins. If CDF doesn't compute DFT will fail. As for why the CDF fails I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndyRoss: Thanks Andy - I'm thinking `bug` tag might be appropriate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently in version 9 listability of the CDF for `TransformedDistribution`, at least in this particular case, was broken.  As of version 10 this is no longer the case.

However, there does appear to be a bug here. Named tests like `PearsonChiSquareTest` actually call `DistributionFitTest` under the hood so I will use the former to help point to the problem.

The `HypothesisTestData` object has some developer properties that illuminate that the problem occurs in the binning of the data.

```
htd = PearsonChiSquareTest[rv, dist, "HypothesisTestData"];
htd["CompleteTestStatistic"]

(* {{{360., {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, "PearsonChiSquare"}} *)
```

The second argument contains the counts of data in the various bins that the test has automatically computed. Note that they are all empty.

However, with your user defined distribution the bins get filled up with data.

```
htd = PearsonChiSquareTest[rv, myPD, "HypothesisTestData"];
htd["CompleteTestStatistic"]

(* {{{15.7633, {29, 21, 48, 50, 56, 63, 28, 40, 17, 8}}, "PearsonChiSquare"}} *)
```

I suspect the issue may be that `Quantile` cannot be computed for `dist` and `DistributionFitTest` isn't handling this well.

```
Quantile[dist, .5]

(* Quantile[
 TransformedDistribution[\[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]2, {\[FormalX]1 \
\[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], \[FormalX]2 \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}], 0.5] *)

Quantile[myPD, .5]

(* 7 *)
```

Comment: Neat analysis, +1 and accept, will add bug tag.